# How to run an ajaxcall after another completes?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Just wondering, in my opinion the code below is able to run a second ajaxfunction when the first one completes.

```
if(xmlHttp) // xmlHttp is an XMLHttpRequest object
  {
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      {
         // second call can be made here because a first one is ready?
      }
   }
```

Am I correct on this? Or do I misunderstand the thing I want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. This is basically how event-driven code works. One event triggers another triggers another... But for code legibility, put your second call into a separate function and have the success handler in the first ajax block call that function. Otherwise you're going to end up with code indented a mile deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that, but it might be better to call a function that does your second request flow.